# Issues reading PDF to NetSuite using C#

Tags: c#, netsuite

In my RESTlet I see an error in my log: Code: **UNEXPECTED_ERROR null Code: UNEXPECTED_ERROR**:

```
var pdf = data.pdfdoc;
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'in data', pdf);
```

I think the data being passed in is not correctly read. Anything look unusual?

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\simplified.PDF", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();

            string jsonString = "{\"tranid\":\"18810\", \"pdfdoc\":\"" + fileBytes + "\"" + "}";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://rest.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=332&deploy=1");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization:NLAuth nlauth_account=XXX, nlauth_email=test@test.com, nlauth_signature=xxx, nlauth_role=18");
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(jsonString);
            }

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.Write(response);
            Console.Read();

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
    }
```

EDIT - code is now creating the pdf doc in NetSuite but not showing the content.

RESTlet

```js
 try
 {
  var file = datain.file;
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'in data', file);
  var base64content = nlapiEncrypt(file, 'base64', null);
  var doc = nlapiCreateFile('mydoc2.pdf', 'PDF', base64content);
  doc.setFolder(115);
  var fileid = nlapiSubmitFile(doc);
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'after submit', fileid);
 }
```

Comment: I believe NetSuite expects any binary data to come in base64 encoded.

Comment: So if I do this: string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes); How would I then pass the string to stream.Read since I get cannot convert from string to byte?

Comment: I don't know anything about the C# file reading API. All I know is that I believe whatever you pass in the HTTP request to NetSuite needs to be base64.

Comment: File is getting created but the content is not showing - error occurs presumably because the content is binary so thought we could use nlapiEncrypt but that doesn't work.

 try
 {
  var file = datain.file;
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'in data', file);
  var base64content = nlapiEncrypt(file, 'base64', null);
  var doc = nlapiCreateFile('mydoc2.pdf', 'PDF', base64content);
  doc.setFolder(115);

  var fileid = nlapiSubmitFile(doc);
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'after submit', fileid);
 }

Comment: Managed to resolve it. Instead of datain.file i needed datain.pdfdoc